# Getting a p-value of 0 on a normal distribution

Tags: python, plot, statistics, normal-distribution, p-value

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wine = pd.read_csv('red wine quality.csv')
wine = wine.dropna()
wine_density = wine[['density']] # Isolating column 'density'
wine_density = wine_density.squeeze() # Reformating as pd.Series
wine_density = pd.to_numeric(wine_density) # Converting from Str to numeric
from scipy import stats
stat, p1 = stats.shapiro(wine_density)
print('Statistics = {0:.3f}, p = {1:.3f}'.format(stat, p1))
alpha = 0.05
if p1 > alpha:
    print('Fail to reject H0, sample is normal.')
else:
    print('Reject H0, sample is NOT normal.)')
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
runcell(9, 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/DSCI 200/Week 8/Week8_Final_Project.py')
Statistics = 0.991, p = 0.000
Reject H0, sample is NOT normal.)
```

However, when I run graphical normality tests such as the qqtest or a histogram, respectively, I get:

```
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
qqplot(wine_density, line = 's')
plt.show()
```

[image: Normality qqtest]

and

```
plt.hist(wine_density, bins=50)
plt.show()
```

[image: Normality histogram]

Both images look like normal distribution to me, but even if they aren't, getting a p value of absolute zero seems erroneous. What am I misunderstanding and/or doing wrong?

Comment: Well, this is a general problem with significance tests. No real distribution is exactly normal, so a significance test must reject the null hypothesis when the sample is large enough. A better question is, how close to normal is this distribution, and is it close enough to work for my purposes? Follow ups to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Robert Dodier, should I repost this same question on stats.stackexchange.com, then?

Comment: Well, my advice is to repost, but if you have learned anything while working on this problem, include that too.

Comment: I will do that, thank you.